# What are the chances of elemental effects of the attacks in Age of Wonders I?

Tags: age-of-wonders

When striking someone with an elemental attack, e.g. *Poison Darts*, or *Lightning Strike*, there is a chance to apply a secondary effect depending on damage type, e.g. deal damage over time if the target is set on fire by a fire-based attack, or disabling the target for 1 turn if the target was affected by a status effect of a lightning-based attack.

However, I would like to know: **What is the chance of applying such a condition?**

Comment: I don't know, whether there are exact numbers for this anywhere. The only thing I can tell you is, that it depends on the defenders resistance stat.